# how do I allocate more than one byte arrays to be added to a queue in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How do I allocate a fixed size new byte() array?

I will then read bytes into it,
append it onto a queue, 
and repeat multiple times to get multiple arrays stored on the queue.

Comment: `Dim someByte As Byte() = New Byte(99) {} `, `Dim someotherByte(99) As Byte`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dim someByte As Byte() = New Byte(99) {}
– answer from Jimi May above

And to deallocate the memory:
someByte = New Byte() {}

Answer (score 0):

Allocate byte array with length 10

```
Dim byteArray(10) as Byte
```

Loop through byte array and set/get/do whatever with values

```
For Each b as Byte in byteArray
  b = 1
Next
```